# Data transformation with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have one data.frame with three columns Year, Coefficent_change and Cummulative_Coefficient_changes.

```
Year    Coefficent_change   Cummulative_Coefficient_changes
--------------------------------------------------------------
2014        1,0         
2015        1,1         
2016        1,0         
2017        1,0         
2018        1,0         
2019        1,0         
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Calculation is only for column Cummulative_Coefficient_changes. So formula must be start from buttom and go up.

For last observation, e.g in 2019 Cummulative_Coefficient_changes by default must have value of 1.

For every subsequent observation formula must have same form,

E.g For 2018
      Cummulative_Coefficient_changes2018=Coefficent_change2019*Cummulative_Coefficient_changes2019

E.g For 2014
      Cummulative_Coefficient_changes2014=Coefficent_change2015*Cummulative_Coefficient_changes2015

So at the end, table should look like table below.

```
Year    Coefficent_change   Cummulative_Coefficient_changes
--------------------------------------------------------------
2014        1,0                    1,1
2015        1,1                    1,0
2016        1,0                    1,0
2017        1,0                    1,0
2018        1,0                    1,0
2019        1,0                    1,0
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this with dplyr ?

Comment: Can you check the expected output you provided, because if ``Cummulative_Coefficient_changes2016=Coefficent_change2017*Cummulative_Coefficient_changes2017`` then it should be `1.0`

Comment: You are correct.I already check.I worked with Excel and there are some decimals which is omitted here.But I correct in anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
library(dplyr) 
# read sample data
my_data <- read.table(text = " Year    Coefficient_change
                      2014        1.0         
                      2015        1.1         
                      2016        1.0         
                      2017        1.0         
                      2018        1.0         
                      2019        1.0", header = T) 
my_data

# add the wanted column filled with the defualt value
my_data$Cummulative_Coefficient_changes <- 1.0

# now calculate the right values
my_data %>% 
  arrange(desc(Year)) %>%    # arrange data [descending] by Year
  mutate(Cummulative_Coefficient_changes = 
           lag(Coefficient_change, default = 1.0)*
           lag(Cummulative_Coefficient_changes, default = 1.0))
```